# Using Sequelize findOne returns before function is finished

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, koa, koa-router

I am using Koa router, with Sequelize. And I have used Sequelize init, where the model is created as follows:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // Associations...
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
      timestamps: false,
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

And the koa-router has:

```
router.get('/:id', UserController.get);
```

Middleware has:

```
const db = require('../../../models/index');

module.exports = () => async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    ctx.db = db;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    ctx.status = 500;
  }
};
```

Now, I have the following code:

```
UserController.get = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const user = await ctx.db.User.findOne({
      where: { id: ctx.params.id });

    if (user) {
      ctx.body = user;
      ctx.status = 200;
    } else {
      ctx.status = 404;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ctx.status = 500;
  }
};
```

When I was stepping through debugger, I am seeing when the debugger moves to `if (user) {` line the response from this GET request returns as 404, even though the function `UserController.get` is not complete yet.

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const user = await ctx.db.User.findOne({
    where: { id: ctx.params.id }
});
```

You forgot a closing bracket

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo when I was copy-pasting the code. But, still the error persists. And in fact, it was retrieving the values from the database correctly, but when it retrieves the value, it is too late, by that time the http response has already been sent.